# Removing item from JList with JButton, but won't refresh

Tags: java, user-interface, refresh, jlist, repaint

I've searched and searched and found like 800 solutions, but none of 'em seems to work with my problem. I'm removing an item from a JList using a JButton, and then i want to refresh the GUI in the actionPerformed method. But things like repaint() or updateUI() hasn't helped. Here is my code:

```
public class Watchlist3 extends JPanel {

public static ArrayList<String> stocks = new ArrayList<String>();

JButton addStock, removeStock, viewStock, updaterInterval;
JLabel stocksAdded, currentInterval, listTitle;
JList stocklist;
JScrollPane listScroller;

    public Watchlist3(JFrame frame) {
    super(new BorderLayout());

   //Adding some sample-components to the list
    stocks.add("PLUG");
    stocks.add("IDN");
    stocks.add("GOOG");

    //Create the components
    addStock = new JButton("Add Stock");
    addStock.setOpaque(true);
    addStock.setBackground(Color.RED);
    add(addStock, BorderLayout.LINE_START);

    removeStock = new JButton("Remove Stock");
    removeStock.setOpaque(true);
    removeStock.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    removeStock.putClientProperty("SENT_FRAME", frame);
    add(removeStock, BorderLayout.LINE_END);


    stocklist = new JList(stocks.toArray());
    stocklist.setOpaque(true);
    stocklist.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    stocklist.setLayoutOrientation(JList.HORIZONTAL_WRAP);
    add(listScroller = new JScrollPane(stocklist), BorderLayout.CENTER);

removeStock.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                int index = stocklist.getSelectedIndex();
                if(index != -1){
                    stocks.remove(index);
                    System.out.println(stocks);

                    /* Here is where id like to refresh the gui! */
                }   
            } catch (Exception ex) {}
        }
    }); 
}

private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    //Create and set up the window.
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Watchlist");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //Create and set up the content pane.
    Watchlist3 newContentPane = new Watchlist3(frame);
    newContentPane.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
    frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

    //Display the window.
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
    //creating and showing this application's GUI.
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You are removing from stocks List collection but not updating the JList model.

To update list model you need put this

```
// Add this item to the list and refresh

// convert stock list to Object array becuase seListData accept Object[]
Object[] array = stocks.toArray(new Object[stocks.size()]);
stocklist.setListData(array);
listScroller.revalidate();
listScroller.repaint();
```